# How to setup KVM partitions?

Tags: linux, partition, kvm, ssd

I am a complete beginner at Linux.

I'm trying to install SolusVM/KVM on a server with one 500 GB HD and one 256 SSD.

SolusVM has a script on the site to download and install automatically, but how do I specify to install the script on the 500 GB HD and put the virtual machines on the SSD?

And how should my partitioning look like? I want KVM ISOs and stuff on HD and virtual machines on SSD.